# The Having statement does not work in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Try to write a query like this:

```
select distinct S.course_id,count(S.course_id)
from Section As S
Where Exists (Select S.course_id
             From Section 
             Where S.year='2019'
             Having count(S.course_id)>1 )
Group by S.course_id
Order by S.course_id DESC;
```

But the result countinue to give me course_ids that does not appear more than once.

| course_id | count(S.course_id) |
| --- | --- |
| PHY-101 | 1 |
| EE-181 | 1 |
| CMPE-347 | 1 |
| CMPE-190 | 2 |
| CMPE-101 | 1 |
| BIO-101 | 1 |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atde6.png)

Comment: The subquery should probably be _correlated_.

Comment: BTW, you rarely never need to do SELECT DISTINCT when you do GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2):

try amending your query as follows

```
select s.course_id, count(s.course_id)
from Section as s
Where Exists (Select * From Section s2
             Where s2.year='2019' and s2.course_id=s.course_id
             group by s2.course_id
             Having count(*)>1)
Group by s.course_id
Order by s.course_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the subquery basically what you want?

```
Select S.course_id, count(*)
From Section s
Where S.year = '2019'
Group by S.course_id
Having count(*) > 1;
```

If you wanted all offerings, then use window functions:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*, count(*) over (partition by s.year) as cnt
      from section s
      where s.year = '2019'
     ) s
where cnt > 1;
```